# static unordered_map initialization with unions

Tags: c++, static, unions, list-initialization

The following static initializer list M fails but N suceeds, it seems I cannot figure out how to do the unordered_map initialization when a union of 3 const char * pointers is added to the init-list. I tried the . notation to access the fields of the union and the union itself to no avail.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iterator>

struct C {
    int j;
    int i;
};

struct D {
    int j;
    char c;
};

struct E {
    const char *a;
    const char *b;
    const char *c;
}e;

struct A {
    const char *s;
    union {
        C c;
        D d;
        E e;
    } u;
};

std::unordered_map<unsigned int, A> m ({
        {1, {"tom",53,'o'}},
        {2, {"ming",40,41}},
        {3, {"peter","a","b","c"}} });

std::unordered_map<unsigned int, A> n ({
        {1, {"tom",53,'o'}},
        {2, {"ming",40,41}} });,

int main(void) {
    for ( const auto& i : m) {
        const auto& j = i.second;
        if (i.first == 1)
            std::cout << "key: " << i.first << " value: " << j.u.d.j << ":" << j.s << ":" << j.u.d.c << std::endl;
        else if (i.first == 2)
            std::cout << "key: " << i.first << " value: " << j.u.c.j << ":" << j.s << ":" << j.u.c.i << std::endl;
        else if (i.first == 3)
            std::cout << "key: " << i.first << " value: " << j.u.e.a << ":" << j.s << ":" << j.u.e.c << std::endl;
    }

    for ( const auto& i : n) {
        const auto& j = i.second;
        if (i.first == 1)
            std::cout << "key: " << i.first << " value: " << j.u.d.j << ":" << j.s << ":" << j.u.d.c << std::endl;
        else if (i.first == 2)
            std::cout << "key: " << i.first << " value: " << j.u.c.j << ":" << j.s << ":" << j.u.c.i << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Error:
map.cpp:41:32: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::unordered_map::unordered_map()’

Comment: What do you mean by "fails"? The problem description is unclear.

Comment: Of course, it fails, they are not valid `std::initializer_list`s in the first place. The lists are not heterogeneous containers.

Comment: Neither M nor N are heterogeneous, so why does one non-hetero work and another doesnt.

Comment: I added the error at the bottom of the post, I got this to work sort of, it involved not using const char* , which i actually didn't need and then finding a bug in the compiler that incorrectly emits a warning.